# ODBC Connection not appearing SSIS

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis, odbc

I have a System DSN ODBC driver configured correctly on a server (the connection has been tested and works fine).

I've got an SSIS package, and when I try to create an ODBC connection manager, I can't find my ODBC connection in the drop down of data sources.

I've tried refreshing the list, closing and re-opening the solution, even re-creating the solution.

Has anyone experienced this before and if so how did you resolve it?

Many thanks

Comment: what operating system are you running? is it 32 bit or 64 bit?

Answer (score 6):

Most likely you have configured the system DNS on a 64-bit Windows, but the SSIS package runs in a 32-bit environment.

> System DSNs will only be seen by the applications and tools which can
>   use them -- 32-bit DSNs for 32-bit applications, and 64-bit DSNs for
>   64-bit applications. [Source](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/UdaWikiWeb/Win32vs64OdbcAdmin?command=plain-html)

For reference, the ODBC Administrator Window can be found in the following locations on a 64-bit environment.

1. C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe (64-bit ODBC Administrator)
2. C:\Windows\SysWoW64\odbcad32.exe (32-bit ODBC Administrator)

Comment: It's like Microsoft is trying to be intentionally confusing by putting the 32 bit DSNs in the folder called "SysWow64" and the 64 bit ones in System32... same with the registry folders...