# I am not able to see ODBC 64-bit drivers in SSIS connection manager drop down list?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2017, odbc, etl

I am not able to see ODBC 64-bit drivers in the SSIS connection manager dropdown list? only 32-bit drivers are appearing in the Visual Studio 2017 SSIS project. Any solution to see a list of available DSN 64-bit ODBC drivers?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can see 64-bit ODBC sources using Visual Studio since [it is a 32-bit application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516436/visual-studio-64-bit) and ODBC 64-bit DSN only appears within 64-bit applications.

### Workaround

Create two ODBC DSN (32-bit and 64-bit) having the same name. Then run the package in 64-bit mode then it will connect to the 64-bit DSN.

This workaround is mentioned in the [ThoughtSpot ODBC Driver guide for SSIS](https://docs.thoughtspot.com/6.0/data-integrate/clients/set-up-the-odbc-driver-using-ssis.html).

---

### External Links

- [ODBC Connection not appearing SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51769240/odbc-connection-not-appearing-ssis)
- [How to run SSIS packages using 32-bit drivers on a 64-bit machine](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/how-to-run-ssis-packages-using-32-bit-drivers-on-a-64-bit-machine)
- [How to execute a 32 bit SSIS package in a 64bit package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28218901/how-to-execute-a-32-bit-ssis-package-in-a-64bit-package)

Comment: Then how can I test connectivity when adding Oracle ODBC in connection managers in SSIS? Oracle does not allow any connections from 32bit ODBC driver connections.

Comment: @Krishna why it doesn't allow connections using 32bit ODBC?